# Which hook should be used to run a cron job in prestashop?

Tags: cron, prestashop

I am making a prestashop module in which I need to run cron job after every 20 minutes. I didn't find any hook for that. All I found is "Cron task manager" module but I don't want to use a module for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like this in the Prestashop Core and module, but anyway, things can be simply done :

- Call a function in module constructor, so it will be executed each time

  ```
  $this->mySuperCron();
  ```
- Then store a time and just check time before executing your request :

  ```
  private function mySuperCron() {
       $check_time = strtotime('now - 20 minutes');

       if ( (int) Configuration::get('MYSUPERMODULETIMER') < (int) $check_time ) {
         // Make your cron here by either calling functions here or do it with file_get_contents / curl or echo an ajax which will be executed in backoffice
         Configuration::updateValue('MYSUPERMODULETIMER', (int) $check_time);
       }

  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you so much for response.

Comment: Dont forger to flag the answer as accepted if it's the case !

Comment: Hi, I got an error when loading the prestashop's website on server, PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Media::replaceByAbsoluteURL() in /mnt/volume-sgp1-02/public_html/classes/Tools.php on line 2210

Comment: can you please help?

Comment: You should open another question as it's not related.

Comment: hello..Cron is not working when  add file path like this:- private function mySuperCron() {
   $check_time = strtotime('now - 20 minutes');

   if ( (int) Configuration::get('MYSUPERMODULETIMER') < (int) $check_time ) {
  
     $this->display(__FILE__, 'myob-cron.php');
     Configuration::updateValue('MYSUPERMODULETIMER', (int) $check_time);
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

Matt's example is good, but it may not work beacause `$check_time` will always be higher than `Configuration::get('MYSUPERMODULETIMER')`.

I fixed that like this:

```php
$next = strtotime('now + 15 minutes');

if ( (int) Configuration::get('MYSUPERMODULETIMER') < (int) strtotime('now') ) {
    // Make your cron here by either calling functions here or do it with file_get_contents / curl or echo an ajax which will be executed in backoffice
    Configuration::updateValue('MYSUPERMODULETIMER', (int) $next);
}
```